# Symfony2 How to check in action or template that i18n is switch off for current action (route)?

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to switch off the language switcher for actions that has i18n disabled in route.
I do not want to hardcode actions identifiers anywhere, instead I would like to get information about status of i18n for current template/action.

```
/**
 * @Route("/path", name="route_name", options={"i18n" = false})
 * @Template("someAppBundle:Frontend/Home:something.html.twig")
 */
public function somethingAction()
{
    //How to check here if i18n is switch off?
    //How to check it directly in twig template?
    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can access route options via

```
$request->attributes->get('i18n')
```

or (in twig):

```
app.request.attributes.get('i18n')
```